# VBA - How can I capture part of a variable path?

Tags: vba

I need to retrieve part of a variable from MicroStation. I can assign a variable for the full path e.g.
`UserName=.ExpandConfigurationVariable("$(_USTN_USER)")`

which will give me:
`W:\Bentley\V8i\SS3\Workspace\users\MyNameHere\`

I want to collect MyNameHere without any path details and the end "\"

Is there a simple way to do this? - The path up to MyNameHere will be constant but the user names will vary in length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this in VBA, use the `Environ` function will return the username:

```
UserName = Environ("username")
```

If that doesn't work, simple string functions:

```
Username = Replace(Mid(.ExpandConfigurationVariable("$(_USTN_USER)"), 36),"/",vbNullString)
```

Comment: Thanks David, the Eviron method seems a good solution in this instance. Your second solution works but leaves me with "/" at the end e.g. MyName/ but I'm sure it will help with other path variables that I'll be coming across.

Comment: The second option *shouldn't leave a trailing slash, that's what the `Replace` function should be doing :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'FileSystemObject' (often abbreviated to `FSO`) from *Microsoft Scripting Runtime*.    FSO provides several methods that work with paths, and let you parse fragments of a file path.